# Creating a new column based on values of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 50], 'b': [5, -2, 20]})
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
    a   b      c
0  10   5     105
1  20  -2     20.58
2  50  20     12.348
```

I have an initial value which is 1000. The first row of `c` is calculated like this:

(1000 * 0.1) * 1.05

Columns `a` and `b` are percent. That is 10 percent of 1000 is 100 and then I want to add 5 percent to 100 which gives me 105 for first row. Then for the next row of `c`, I want to calculate 20 percent of 105 which is 21 and then subtract 2 percent of it which is 20.58.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
df['b'] = df['b'] / 100
df['c'] = (df.a / 100).cumprod() * 1000
df['c'] = df.c * (1 + df.b)
```

Feel free to edit the title. I want something more specific but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `cumprod` too:

```
(df.a / 100 * (1 + df.b / 100)).cumprod() * 1000

#0    105.000
#1     20.580
#2     12.348
#dtype: float64
```

---

Basically for each row, you need `a` + the percentage of `b` on `a`. Hence `a + a * b`, used `/ 100` to convert to percentage first.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
out, cur = [], 1000
for a, b in zip(df.a / 100, df.b / 100):
    tmp = cur * a
    out.append(cur := tmp + tmp * b)

df['c'] = out
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    a   b        c
0  10   5  105.000
1  20  -2   20.580
2  50  20   12.348
```